# I have tried to add a Facebook login button, but no matter what, after pressing it there's an error

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am developing an app and the first thing I want is to add the Facebook login. I have followed the steps from `developer.facebook.com`, but it doesn't work. The issue is that every time I press the "Continue with Facebook" button, it generates an error in a Toast message. This is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.android.loginfacebookexemplu;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private CircleImageView circleImageView;
    private TextView txtName,txtEmail;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        txtName = findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
        txtEmail = findViewById(R.id.profile_email);
        circleImageView = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","public_profile"));
        checkLoginStatus();

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Utilizator conectat",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Conexiune anulata",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"A aparut o eroare la conectare, te rugam sa reincerci",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    AccessTokenTracker tokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken)
        {
            if(currentAccessToken==null)
            {
                txtName.setText("");
                txtEmail.setText("");
                circleImageView.setImageResource(0);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Utilizator deconectat",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
                loadUserProfile(currentAccessToken);
        }
    };

    private void loadUserProfile(AccessToken newAccessToken)
    {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(newAccessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "CheckResult"})
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
            {
                try {
                    String first_name = object.getString("first_name");
                    String last_name = object.getString("last_name");
                    String email = object.getString("email");
                    String id = object.getString("id");
                    String image_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+ "/picture?type=normal";

                    txtEmail.setText(email);
                    txtName.setText(first_name +" "+last_name);
                    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                    requestOptions.dontAnimate();

                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(image_url).into(circleImageView);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields","first_name,last_name,email,id");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }

    private void checkLoginStatus()
    {
        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null)
        {
            loadUserProfile(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
        }
    }
}
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.loginfacebookexemplu">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

And I also updated the `build.gradle` as facebook's page suggested, with the internet permission and the meta-data. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error? Show us the error you are getting.

Comment: I do not receive an error in logs, the app just returns me the "Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"A aparut o eroare la conectare, te rugam sa reincerci",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();" from "public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)"

Comment: Rather than showing you custom text for first development purposes show the error only then you can know the real problem. Use Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error "+error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: I just verified and it was because on developers.facebook i had the Key Hash entered from cmd, using their steps. But the phone used other key hash. Once I entered that too on developers.facebook for my app, the connection worked on my phone. The question is now, if anyone else wants to use the app and facebook login, how can i update the key hash for evey user? Shouldn't it go itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    LoginButton loginButton;
     CallbackManager callbackManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);


        boolean loggedOut = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null;

        if (!loggedOut) {
            Picasso.with(this).load(Profile.getCurrentProfile().getProfilePictureUri(200, 200)).into(imageView);
            Log.d("TAG", "Username is: " + Profile.getCurrentProfile().getName());

            //Using Graph API
            getUserProfile(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
        }

        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
                //loginResult.getAccessToken();
                //loginResult.getRecentlyDeniedPermissions()
                //loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions()
                boolean loggedIn = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null;
                Log.d("API123", loggedIn + " ??");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void getUserProfile(AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                currentAccessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.d("TAG", object.toString());
                        try {
                            String first_name = object.getString("first_name");
                            String last_name = object.getString("last_name");
                            String email = object.getString("email");
                            String id = object.getString("id");
                            String image_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=normal";




                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "first_name,last_name,email,id");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }
}
```

Manifest File

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" 
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Dependencies

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
```

Happy Coding :)